# Stripe API key missing in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, stripe-payments, initializer

I am trying to setup Stripe checkout as described in this [GoRails episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKWq_soCzsQ&t=325s)

I have defined the publishable_key and secret_key in application.yml using the figaro gem so in my config/initializers/stripe.rb I have this code

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV["public_key"],
  :secret_key      => ENV["private_key"]
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]

puts Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key]
puts Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
puts Stripe.api_key
```

Now, I know that up to this point everything is fine because the keys are printed in the console when the server starts.

However, when the action goes to the controller I get a message saying

> "No API key provided. Set your API key using "Stripe.api_key =
> ". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface.
> See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if
> you have any questions."

The only way I can make it work is by re-setting the stripe API key inside the controller action by

```
class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController
  
  def show
    Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key] #<---Have to re-set the API key

    current_user.set_payment_processor :stripe
    
    @checkout_session = current_user.payment_processor.checkout(
      # mode: "payment",
      # line_items: "price_1KuweRFkaCcck7q2JSu01hHi"
      mode: "subscription",
      line_items: "price_1KuyuVFkaCcck7q23EJLLpra"
      )    
  end  
end
```

Why doesn't the controller recognize something that was defined in the initializer?

Answer (score -1):

This is a variable scope issue. The stripe instance used in your controller is different than the one in your initializer. I would follow that video more closely from the beginning and use the same strategy that's used there.